# Translate reversed hostnames to regular hostnames from a file

Tags: linux

I have a big file containing reversed hostnames like,

- com.example
- au.test
- uk.follow
- org.dev
- io.github
- nl.payper

How can I translate all the reversed hostnames and save the result in a text file? E.g. translate  from `com.example` to `example.com` or `nl.payper` to `payper.nl`

I have not looked into any method myself yet.

Answer (score 6):

You can use awk with a custom delimiter for that:

```
<hostnames.txt awk -F. 'NF {print $2"."$1}' >output.txt
```

Explanation:

- With `<filename` a file is passed to stdin
- "-F" sets the delimiter to "." (dot)
- The "NF" at the beginning makes awk ignore emtpy lines
- With the print command the second value, a dot and the first value are printed
- With `>output.txt` the result of the command is saved into that specified file

Comment: This can be generalized to [support arbitrary number of fields](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594683/108618).

Comment: Yeah, right. Good idea. But joining the parts with dot might be a bit more complex